# How to get PID of process by specifying process name and store it in a variable to use further?

Tags: unix, process, pid

By using "ucbps" command i am able to get all PIDs

```
 $ ucbps

   Userid     PID     CPU %  Mem %  FD Used   Server                  Port
   =========================================================================

   512        5783    2.50   16.30  350       managed1_adrrtwls02     61001
   512        8896    2.70   21.10  393       admin_adrrtwls02        61000
   512        9053    2.70   17.10  351       managed2_adrrtwls02     61002
```

I want to do it like this, but don't know how to do

1. variable=get pid of process by processname.
2. Then use this command kill -9 variable.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

If you want to kill -9 based on a string (you might want to try kill first) you can do something like this:

```
ps axf | grep <process name> | grep -v grep | awk '{print "kill -9 " $1}'
```

This will show you what you're about to kill (very, very important) and just pipe it to `sh` when the time comes to execute:

```
ps axf | grep <process name> | grep -v grep | awk '{print "kill -9 " $1}' | sh
```

Comment: a way to avoid the "grep -v grep" is to use "grep <process nam[e]>" so it interpolates the string and the process nam[e] isn't found when the first grep executes, if that makes sense.

Comment: I think this is easier 
pgrep -f <process name> | awk '{print "kill -9 " $1}' | sh

Answer (score 84):

```
pids=$(pgrep <name>)
```

will get you the pids of all processes with the given name. To kill them all, use

```
kill -9 $pids
```

To refrain from using a variable and directly kill all processes with a given name issue

```
pkill -9 <name>
```

Comment: $ pids=$(pgrep admin_adrrtwls02)
$ kill -9 $pids
Usage: kill [-l] [-n signum] [-s signame] job ...
   Or: kill [ options ] -l [arg ...]

Comment: Unix programs tend print out their usage description when needed arguments are not given. In your example, most probably no process with the name admin_adrrtwls02 was found. Therefore $pids evaluates to the empty string and kill is executed without a process id argument. pgrep searches for a process name, not for the user name. But there also are the flags -u and -U to restrict pgrep to given user ids.

Comment: there was process with this name admin_adrrtwls02. The above answer by Ben solved my problem. His solution worked.

Comment: pkill doesn't require -9. For example you can use pkill firfox.

Comment: `-9`, used to send `SIGKILL`, is not required, but mentioned in the question. Without it, the less violent `SIGTERM` (Signal number 15) will be sent.

Comment: Tip: to convert the pids string into an array use `pidArray=(${pids})`

Comment: True, but kill -9 is safer. For example I was trying to remove a virus from a friend's computer, and the program completely ignored kill without the -9.

Comment: use the `-x` flag for `pkill` (and `pgrep`) to do an exact match rather than a substring match.

Answer (score 37):

On a single line...

```
pgrep -f process_name | xargs kill -9
```

Comment: As already mentioned in other comments the `-f` parameter could be helpful here

`       -f     The pattern is normally only matched against the process name.  When -f is set, the full command line is used.`

`pgrep -f process_name | xargs kill -9`

Answer (score 18):

Another possibility would be to use `pidof` it usually comes with most distributions. It will return you the PID of a given process by using it's name.

```
pidof process_name
```

This way you could store that information in a variable and execute `kill -9` on it.

```
#!/bin/bash
pid=`pidof process_name`
kill -9 $pid
```

Answer (score 0):

use grep [n]ame to remove that grep -v name this is first... Sec using xargs in the way how it is up there is wrong to rnu whatever it is piped you have to use -i ( interactive mode) otherwise you may have issues with the command.

ps axf | grep  | grep -v grep | awk '{print "kill -9 " $1}' ? 
ps aux |grep [n]ame | awk '{print "kill -9 " $2}' ? isnt that better ?

Comment: even better:  pidof name |xargs -i kill -9 {} ? no ?

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution (Exact Process Name Match)

```bash
pgrep -x <process_name> | xargs kill -9
```

(incidentally, for this specific use case, might as well do `pkill -9 -x <process_name>`, but the question asked how to get the PID in general)

##### Details

The problem with the accepted answer (and all other answers) is that `pgrep` without `-x` (or manually `ps | grep`, or, for some reason, `pidof`) will match processes for which the `<process_name>` term is a *substring*.

So, for example, `pgrep installd` matches, on my machine (`macOS 13.0 22A380 arm64`) now:

```bash
❯ pgrep -l installd
316 uninstalld
33158 system_installd
33160 installd
```

I obviously only want `33160`, not the other ones.

For some reason, `pidof` has the same issue:

```bash
❯ pidof installd
316 33158 33160
```

`pregp -x` is the the only viable solution (beyond messing around with regexes with the `ps | grep` solution, I suppose)

```bash
❯ pgrep -xl installd
33160 installd
```